# Gmail Notifications on my Galaxy Note10

Tags: samsung, gmail, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I've used Galaxy Note 10 for about 6 months and one of the major issues that I have experienced was related to my gmail notification. I’d go several hours without receiving any emails and just think to check the app and as soon as I open the app then I’d have like 20 emails just sitting there that I had never received a push notification. Do you know any easy fix for this?

Comment: Maybe Gmail is optimized (see battery optimization seems). If it is , disable

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to **Settings > Device Care > Battery > App power management > Apps that won't be put to sleep**.  Add Gmail to this list to prevent it from being put to sleep for battery optimization. You could also disable this feature entirely by disabling "Put unused apps to sleep."